# How to center text block?

Tags: html, css

I have the following content that I'd like to center horizontally in a page.  However, it keeps left aligning.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```css
#container {
    width: 800px;
 margin: auto 0;
}

article {
 width:200px;
 margin: auto 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <article>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries.</article>
</div>
```

Comment: `with` must be `width`!

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this by replace the `margin: auto 0;` with `margin: 0 auto;` like this:

```css
#container {
 width:800px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

article {
 width:200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <article>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries.</article>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes - so just a matter of switching the "auto 0" part.

Answer (score 1):

```
#container {
    width:800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

article {
    width:200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

<div id="container">
    <article>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries.</article>
</div>
```

Spell and Value changed are done.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this sort of functionality multiple ways.

If you know the width of the element (200px), position it 50% from the left, then do a negative margin-left equal to half the element's width (-100px).

```
article {
   position:relative;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -100px;
   width: 200px;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ADTfAMlsyvTf46Ag35u4?p=preview

Set a width on the element and set margin: 0 auto. When you specify margin with 2 values (ie. margin: x x) the first value will be applied to the top and bottom while the second value is applied to the left and right. Therefore it will automatically position itself in the middle. Setting margin: auto 0 will position the content in the top left, which is why you are seeing it left aligned.

```
article {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/MkZR6BUUzMD6LoWMuUPF?p=preview